# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar Spring 5.0 en NetBeans?

Tags: spring-mvc, netbeans-8.2

Cuándo creo un proyecto Java Web en NetBeans y selecciono un Framework, en este caso Spring Web MVC, solamente me aparecen dos opciones:

- Versión 4.0.1
- Versión 3.2.7

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]